# How to nest diffierent resource files in MFC?

Tags: c++, mfc

I am combining two projects and I get stuck when I try to nest the resource files.
I use resource include command and include the affiliated rc file in the main rc file. Add the
" #include affiliated.rc" in the compile-time directives field. But it doesn't work. Fatal error CVT1100:  comes up. Can sombody help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resource files cannot be nested. You can attach multiple resources to a binary. All these resources should have different IDs (names or numbers). Resource is picked by this ID. They do not form any sort of directory structure.

You need to add multiple resource files to your project and ensure that all individual resources have different ids, i.e. rename some of them. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3k67zd6z(v=vs.71).aspx. This error directly states this.

Comment: When I add new resource file to a binary, a correlative head file will be created, named resource1.h, and I have to include the resource1.h at all the cpp files that use the symbols. But in this page,http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t3612sk(v=vs.80).aspx ,Using Multiple Resource Files in the Same Project , I can include one .rc file in the main .rc file without adding a new head file. Am I wrong?

Comment: You are free to delete/rename this header file. I never use auto created files. I always write my own. Edit the header file and include it manually where it is needed. C++ compiler and linker do not know who created this file. Project can contain several .rc files like linker can work with multiple .obj files. You do not need to call one .rc from the other.

Comment: I do not know who clicked -1. Don't worry, your post is fine.

Comment: I do success run the project buy editing the header file manually when I use two resource files but do not nest.But it fails when I try to split the string tables into two rc files. And when I try to nest as the appWizard does, say the afxres.rc file, it doesn't work. Anyway, I don't have any better way so far, thanks a lot!